# How to print out the parameters change in nlsLM function in R?

Tags: r, nls, s

I want to see how [the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zylm.png) change with the change of MSE. I want to print all the values of the parameters and the MSE associated with it?

Comment: Hi Ryan. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are much more likely to get the help you need here if you give us enough information to work with. Please include a reproducible example including sample data and code, so that we can run your example ourselves. Please don't use _pictures_ of data or code, as these are not reproducible, since they cannot be copy/pasted into a console, as would be necessary to generate and test possible solutions.

Comment: Set argument `trace = TRUE`. And post in which package can `nlsLM` function be found, [`minpack.lm`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=minpack.lm)?